# correct way to arrange buttons div in web development

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, cross-browser

I'm new to web development and trying to understand the "best"/"correct"/"smart" way to arrange divs of buttons (if multiple divs are even necessary).

for example, I am trying to make a volume button which will mute/unmute audio, and have a volume slider next to it (like the one on you tube).

How should I create it? with a parent div, and a div "per-feature", or maybe just a single div inside a big div?
what would give the most flexible way to add functionality later?

Example: option 1 - three divs, option 2 - two divs
[image]

Maybe something else?

Also, Where can I find information about conventions or about how to "think" in a correct web development way.

Thanks!

Comment: Would be good if post some code that you tried which is not giving this result?

Comment: Try to use as few elements as possible. With the flexbox positioning, you probably don't need any div wrappers at all, just your button and slider inside a controls div. (also note that this question might be closed as opinion-based)

Comment: Try to use flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Bharat Thanks, but I am not trying to get help with the code itself, but rather understand concept.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your reply. Why is using as few elements as possible better sometimes? won't it limit my options later? Let's say I want to show the slider only on hover. Does using only a single div element is still good? In general - what should I think about when facing such decisions? Thanks!

Comment: The less elements the more readable your code will be. For instance there's a trope to create navigation using nav > ul > li > a, which can simply be done with nav > a instead. Showing an element only on hover does not necessarily mean you have to wrap it in a separate div. You simply do `.container:hover .vol-slider { display: block; }` for instance. Also, why would it limit your options? If it becomes clear that you will need additional nesting, you can simply add it at any point, right?

Comment: @ChrisG I think I understand what you mean, but while it is possible to add elements at any point, it's not always simple. I though that I should use more elements in advance and put "one functionality per element". Reading what you wrote made me realize it should probably be the opposite, and try to add as few elements as possible. Is there a place to read about "good" web programming practice? I couldn't find something that would answer the dilemma I had here

Comment: You need to experiment, but I suggest learning about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). It makes lots of nesting unnecessary. However the most important thing is practice. Spend a few years building websites and questions like this will answer themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sample

```css
.btn {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Darker background on mouse-over */
  .btn:hover {
    background-color: RoyalBlue;
  }
  .divred {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;

    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
  }

  .column {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container column">
      <div class="divred">
        <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></button>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" />
      </div>
      <div class="divred">
        <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></button>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure I understand your answer. Is this an example of 2 different implementations? Could you explain the difference or what you did here?

Comment: I thought you were looking for two line :) lol. My bad. No difference in two divs. But is this what you were looking for? Apologies, if I completely misunderstood the question

Comment: All good. I only showed it as examples for some options it could be done in and was looking to hear about pros and cons of choosing the better ways to design these kind of things

Comment: Since the number of controls are less, simple flex, table, bootstrap columns any of them would work